# Using a ComboBox with ValidationRules in a ListView

Tags: wpf, validation, combobox, validationrules

I have a Listview with a column containing a TextBox and another column with a ComboBox.

This validation works just fine for the TextBox:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="SQL Server">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Width="140">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Server" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnValidationError="True" 
                             ValidatesOnExceptions="True" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" 
                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <helpers:DatabaseServerNameValidationRule />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

But when I try the same approach with the ComboBox, my validator is never called:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Database Type">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Width="140" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DatabaseTypeFromEnum}}" SelectedItem="{Binding DatabaseType, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                    <Binding Path="DatabaseType" 
                             NotifyOnValidationError="True" 
                             ValidatesOnExceptions="True" 
                             ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" 
                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <helpers:DatabaseTypeValidationRule />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I have also tried replacing `<ComboBox.SelectedValue>` with `<ComboBox.SelectedValuePath>` with no effect.

My issue probably lies in the Binding Path for the ComboBox, but I'm just thrashing at this point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is you have binded **`SelectedItem`** and **`SelectedValue`** both for comboBox. Moreover, they are binded to same property.

***Get rid of SelectedItem binding*** and it will work fine. *(SelectedItem has higher preference over SelectedValue)*

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Database Type">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Width="140"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource 
                                                    DatabaseTypeFromEnum}}">
                <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                    <Binding Path="DatabaseType" 
                             NotifyOnValidationError="True" 
                             ValidatesOnExceptions="True" 
                             ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" 
                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <helpers:DatabaseTypeValidationRule />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: No more `TwoWay` anywhere?

Comment: Default mode is `TwoWay` for `SelectedValue` dependency property. If you still want you can set it `TwoWay` on `Binding`.

Comment: Gotcha. I've tried it both ways, but I don't see my setter being called on my model. The getter is called though. Weird.

Comment: Works fine at my end in small sample where i have tried. Have you make sure that your Validation rule is returning true for valid selection?

Comment: That was it. Returned false. Disabling the rule solved the problem.